# SQL 2008 Version Number Question

Tags: sql-server-2008, service-pack, patching

When I run the SQL Server 2008 Setup Discovery Report, all of the components (Database Engine Services, Management Tools - Complete, etc) show as version 10.3.5852.0.

However, I cannot find any information online as to what this version relates to ?

Any advice or help gratefully received.

Comment: Please add the output of discovery report in your question to make things clear.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [there was a bug](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/524118-sql-server-build-version-numbers) in a previous patch that messed up the version number.  Replace the 3 with 00 and you will find the correct info.  It should be [Cumulative update package 16 for SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 3](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2008/63491/)

Answer (score 0):

You are having SQL Server 2008 and you are worried why version is showing `10.3.5852` instead of `10.0.5852` and this is because of bug for which [connect Item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/806317/sql-server-2008-r2-sp2-discovery-report-bug) was raised and confirmed by MS employee that this is bug.

From incomplete knowledge I have this is happening because SQL Server is reading some random registry values while scanning the registry for installed SQL server versions which it should not.

I believe this should be fixed in Future service pack releases. Since you are on SP2 + some CU I suggest you apply SQL Server 2008 Sp4

To get information about SQL Server version simply run `select @@version`